# How to create bootstrap 5 navbar menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need documentation on how to create a bootstrap menu ([like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)) that will pop up from right to left

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

you can give the main div of navbar these properties

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {right: 0px;}
  to {right: -200px;}
}
```

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.php)